# Why C++ variable template does not raise multiple definitions error?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Seems I lack some rudimentary knowledge how templates work. Consider a program consisting of a common header file that introduces a variable template being a wrapper on `std::array` and two sources that include the header.

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <array>

template <typename T, auto N> std::array<T, N> arr;
void printArr();

#endif
```

source1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

void printArr()
{
    std::cout << &arr<int, 5> << std::endl;
}
```

source2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << &arr<int, 5> << std::endl;
    printArr();
    return 0;
}
```

The program produces following prints:

```
0x565146e1c160
0x565146e1c160
```

Both prints produce the same memory address so the same instance is being manipulated.
My question is why the linker does not raise an error due to multiple definitions at link-time? Is this because the variable template is just a template and respective instances of the template are marked as weak which in turn produces a unique object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-definition rule is relaxed for `inline` functions and variables, as well as for function templates and variable templates:

> For any definable item `D` with definitions in multiple translation units,
>
> - if `D` is a non-inline non-templated function or variable, or
> - if the definitions in different translation units do not satisfy the following requirements,
>
> the program is ill-formed; [...]

- [[basic.def.odr] p14](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14)

In short, the restrictions mean that `arr` can be defined in multiple translation units because it is a variable template. However, it must be defined *exactly* the same way in every TU.

```cpp
// source1.cpp
template <typename T, auto N>
std::array<T, N> arr;

// source2.cpp
template <typename T, auto N>
std::array<T, N> arr; // OK

// source3.cpp
template <typename T, auto>
std::array<T, 10> arr; // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
```

The reason why this doesn't produce a linker error is that that the emitted symbols (e.g. `arr<int, 5>` with its name mangled) are *weak*. Similar to `inline` variables, the linker chooses one of N available definitions under the assumption that all of them are identical. If you follow the rules in [basic.def.odr], then this assumption is fair.

---

#### See Also

- [Are variable templates declared in a header, an ODR violation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70801992/5740428) (the answers here explain how this was worded in the C++ standard historically)